# More efficient way to clean dataframe than loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", header=None, footer=None)
c_df = df.copy()
c_df = c_df.iloc[18:245, 2:]
c_df = c_df.rename(columns={2: 'Country', 3: 'Energy Supply', 4:'Energy Supply per Capita', 5:'% Renewable'})
c_df['Energy Supply'] = c_df['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000)
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Korea, Rep.'] = 'South Korea'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'United States of America20'] = 'United States'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland'] = 'United Kingdom'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region'] = 'Hong Kong'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)'] = 'Venezuela'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)'] = 'Bolivia'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Switzerland17'] = 'Switzerland'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Australia1'] = 'Australia'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'China2'] = 'China'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)'] = 'Bolivia'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Greenland7'] = 'Greenland'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Iran (Islamic Republic of'] = 'Iran'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Italy9'] = 'Italy'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Japan10'] = 'Japan'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Kuwait11'] = 'Kuwait'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Micronesia (Federal States of)'] = 'Micronesia'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Netherlands12'] = 'Netherlands'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Portugal13'] = 'Portugal'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Saudi Arabia14'] = 'Saudi Arabia'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Serbia15'] = 'Serbia'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Sint Maarteen (Dutch part)'] = 'Sint Marteen'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Spain16'] = 'Spain'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Ukraine18'] = 'Ukraine'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Denmark5'] = 'Denmark'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'France6'] = 'France'
c_df.loc[c_df['Country'] == 'Indonesia8'] = 'Indonesia'
```

I feel like there must be an easier way to change the values of the countries with parentheses and numbers in their names. What pandas method can I use to  look within the column for names with numbers of parentheses? `isin`?

Comment: You should make a `dict` which map the Country names and use the `map` function.

Comment: @TwistedSim psst, `map` replaces non-dict entries with NaN, probably not desirable in this case (you want `replace`).

Comment: @COLDSPEED, didn't knew that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start by getting rid of numbers and text in parentheses. After that, for everything else that requires non-trivial replacement, declare a map and apply it using `pd.Series.replace`.

```
mapper = {'Korea, Rep' : 'South Korea', 'Falkland Islands' : 'Bolivia', ...} 

df['Country'] = (
    df['Country'].str.replace(r'\d+|\s*\(.*\)', '').str.strip().replace(mapper)
)
```

Simple enough, done.

**Details**

```
\d+     # one or more digits
|       # regex OR pipe
\s*     # zero or more whitespace characters
\(      # literal parentheses (opening brace)
.*      # match anything 
\)      # closing brace
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the test within the replace method (r'\d+|\s*\(.*\)', '')?

Answer (score 3):

Using a dictionary and then [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
dict_to_replace = {'Korea, Rep.':'South Korea',
                         'United States of America20':'United States',
                         'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom'
                   ...}

df['c_df'] = df['c_df'].replace(dict_to_replace)
```

Comment: ^1, but keep in mind that the dict_to_replace will become unneededly complicated thanks to the specific digits and parenthesis in each entry.

Comment: Lastly, replacement is done on Country only, but the rest of the dataframe is duplicated without reason :o)

Comment: True! I edited my answer to address that second concern, but stripping it and getting rid of the unnecessary things in the original dataframe as you did is probably smarter to end up with a cleaner dict